How to create a mutually exclusive FreeBSD port?
I have created multiply FreeBSD ports of a program, that supports different database flavours (e.g. PostgreSQL, MariaDB, ...). That part is working perfectly fine.
Now I want to create a dependency to all the different program-database ports, but only one should be selected.
I know how to add dependencies to a port with BUILD_DEPENDS and RUN_DEPENDS, but don't know how to make a list mutual exclusive?

You need to declare a package conflict; see the respective section in the porter's guide.
In essence, you need to add
CONFLICTS_INSTALL= your_other_packages

to the port's Makefile.
